# Authenticated user data in a controller with .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm working on a simple app to manage some static IP addresses as a way to learn how to build a full .Net Core application with users and authentication to a production environment.

I started with the .Net Core web application template in Visual Studio 2015 that includes Identity Framework Core and Entity Framework Core. I have built the following Model and generated the controller with CRUD pages from that. All of that works great.

So far I can login/register/logout etc without problems using the built in code. I want to have this data be user specific so User A gets their addresses, and User B gets theirs. So this would involve some kind of foreign key to the Identity Framework tables so it can match IP addresses up to a user and then display them. I was wondering what would be the best way to handle this with .Net Core? I haven't been able to find any examples specific to .Net Core.

Model:

```
public class IpAddress
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string hostname { get; set; }

    [MinLength(9)]
    [MaxLength(21)]
    public string ipv4 { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(45)]
    public string ipv6 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool vm { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool container { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool docker { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string operating_system { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string description { get; set; }
}
```

First part of the controller (Index and Details routes):

```
[Authorize]
public class IpAddressesController : Controller
{
    private readonly IpAddressContext _context;

    public IpAddressesController(IpAddressContext context)
    {
        _context = context;    
    }

    // GET: IpAddresses
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View(await _context.IpAddresses.ToListAsync());
    }

    // GET: IpAddresses/Details/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var ipAddress = await _context.IpAddresses.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.id == id);
        if (ipAddress == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(ipAddress);
    } 
 ...
```

So like I said, I assume it would be as simple as adding a foreign key to the model, and then getting the data in the controller with a Linq query based on that foreign key, right? I'm not very good with Linq, so any help with that would be great. I can definitly provide more code if it would help.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. You need to add a foreign key on your IpAddress table (linking you to the user table):

```
[ForeignKey("ApplicationUser"), Column("Id")]
public int UserId { get; set; }
```

Then add the info on the AspNetUsers table to match

```
[ForeignKey("UserId")]
public virtual IpAddress IpAddress{ get; set; }
```

You will then be able to use LINQ to get the users IP address info, something like:

```
_context.IpAddresses.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.UserId == userIid);
```